# Angularjs UI ui-map does not work for IE8

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui

ui-maps does not load the map in IE8. I'm able to see the map in chrome but it does not work for IE8. Even visiting the link (http://angular-ui.github.io/) with IE8 you can notice that the directive does not bring the map.

Comment: Interesting... Angularjs page brakes with IE8 and exception calls my VS2010 to debug error.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui.github.com/issues/60

Comment: Any comments on this?

Answer (score 0):

user1791567 - please include some sample code or even better a jsfiddle showing the problem.  As it stands its really difficult to debug due to a lack of information.  The map on angular-ui.github.io is gone as well.  If you are referring to the demo in the repository, that is not a fully functioning app on its own...

Also make sure you haven't broken any of the IE incompatibility rules.  See http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie for information.  In particular read through the comments, several of them note IE 8 incompatibilities as well.

As for why the VS2010 debugger is loading, vs.net can be setup as your script debugger and if so exceptions thrown within IE can trigger a load of Visual Studio.